# Making child SKSpriteNode ignore touches

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am adding a SKSpriteNode as a child of an existing SKSpriteNode node but I want the user to still be able to touch the existing parent node underneath (the child is a purely visual element). Is there anyway to add a sprite as a child, have it visible but unseen by touches (and mouse clicks in the simulator).

Comment: I think I might just have fixed this by using nodesAtPoint and then selecting the appropriate node from the returned array.

Comment: How about setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` for the child node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the child sprite will ignore touches, unless it's userInteractionEnabled property is set to YES by you.